# How to configure Node.js ExpressJs for HTTPS?

Tags: nginx, https, ubuntu-16.04, node.js

I am attempting to get an nginx,NodeJs,Express route working correctly on a server instance (Digital Ocean).

So far, this is the situation:

```
What currently works:
http://api.xxxxxx.com - switches to https and returns "Welcome to nginx!" page.
https://api.xxxxxx.com - returns "Welcome to nginx!" page
http://api.xxxxxx.com:3000/xxx/xxxxxxxxx/xx/xxx/xxx.xxx - returns the file byte array.

What doesn't:
https://api.xxxxxx.com:3000/xxx/xxxxxxxxx/xx/xxx/xxx.xxx - Error. "This site can’t provide a secure connection"

What I want to work:
https://api.xxxxxx.com/xxx/xxxxxxxxx/xx/xxx/xxx.xxx
```

I tried to add https to the `bin/www`:

```
var https = require('https');
httpServer.listen(443);
httpServer.on('error', onError);
httpServer.on('listening', onListening);
```

But that resulted in the www process stopping in error.

I am obviously missing something. I am referencing an array of tutorials and docs that get me close but not directly to what I need.  And I am new to all of these components, but this is what I'm working with:

- Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS
- ExpressJs 4.16
- NodeJs 10.15.0
- nginx 1.10.3

What additional steps do I need to take in order to get the 
`https://api.xxxxxx.com/xxx/xxxxxxxxx/xx/xxx/xxx.xxx` request to work?

#### nginx.conf (wispymammal is not the real host)

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections 768;
    # multi_accept on;
}

http {

    ##
    # Basic Settings
    ##

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    # server_tokens off;

    # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    # server_name_in_redirect off;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;



    ##
    # SSL Settings
    ##

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;


      server { # simple reverse-proxy
        listen       443;

        error_log /var/log/nginx/api.wispymammal.error.log;         
        server_name  api.wispymammal.com;
        access_log   logs/api.wispymammal.access.log  main;

        # pass requests for dynamic content to rails/turbogears/zope, et al
        location / {
          proxy_pass      http://localhost:3000;
        }
      }  



    ##
    # Logging Settings
    ##

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    ##
    # Gzip Settings
    ##

    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";

    # gzip_vary on;
    # gzip_proxied any;
    # gzip_comp_level 6;
    # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    # gzip_http_version 1.1;
    # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

    ##
    # Virtual Host Configs
    ##

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}


#mail {
#   # See sample authentication script at:
#   # http://wiki.nginx.org/ImapAuthenticateWithApachePhpScript
# 
#   # auth_http localhost/auth.php;
#   # pop3_capabilities "TOP" "USER";
#   # imap_capabilities "IMAP4rev1" "UIDPLUS";
# 
#   server {
#       listen     localhost:110;
#       protocol   pop3;
#       proxy      on;
#   }
# 
#   server {
#       listen     localhost:143;
#       protocol   imap;
#       proxy      on;
#   }
#}
```

Comment: You do nothing in Node.js; everything is in nginx.

Comment: Can you post the nginx config?  As Michael suggests you should really avoid configuring Node to handle HTTPS connections directly (which you're trying with `var https = require('https');`)  The correct way is to have HTTPS terminate at nginx, and proxy to your Node applicaiton via HTTP which may run on localhost:3000.  Without the `nginx` config here though it's difficult to assist.

Comment: That makes sense. I did try to add  a server block and listen on 443 and add a proxy_pass to http://localhost:3000.  But I get a 404 on that request.